# Is Bokeh capable of being a permanent live dashboard

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

The company I work for is looking to run some live dashboards in the reception area to show performance, geographical location of users etc etc - as such, these wouldn't need to be interactive but instead updating relatively quickly (maybe every 5mins?) and would be on permanently.

Is Bokeh a reasonable solution for this? I've used them in the past for personal dashboards and they look nice and are pretty customisable, so it instantly came to mind.

Thanks in advance for any advice...

Comment: That is quite an open ended question to be honest. As you have said you already used it for a personal dashboard - so what specific questions do you have that you dont know the answers to, which are relevant for this? I mean https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html those are permanent live dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

The apps/dashboards at http://demo.bokeh.org (e.g. one specific one: https://demo.bokeh.org/sliders) have been running continuously without any intervention since `0.12.3` was released, nearly one year ago (early October 2016).

In fact, they run a bit slowly because they are still running on `0.12.3`. I have not had an opportunity to re-deploy them using newer, faster Bokeh versions.